# MVC3 Permissions based checkboxs list

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, permissions

I try to find a way to show / hide actions.
i want to let the system admin choose the specific permissions for the user.
for example: 
read
write
create 
send message
forward message
etc...
each page will contain parts that will or will not shown, depend the permission. 
what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <div>Only administrators can see this message</div>
}
```

Comment: This is not what i mean, lets say that the user has permission to delete but not to create new users but he is a member in Admin Role ?

Comment: In this case you should include this information in your view model as  a boolean property. Inside your controller action you will set this boolean property according to your business needs. And then inside your view simply test `@if (Model.HasPermissioToDoXXX) { ... }`.

Comment: Ok, but if we have 15 kind of permissions all my page will look like if (bla bla){} if (bla bla){} if (bla bla){} and it will be a big mess, is there any other option?

Comment: You could write custom helpers that will conditionally render for example a TextBox given a boolean value -> `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProperty, Model.HasPermissioToDoXXX)`.

Comment: First off all thank you very much for your help :), can you show me an example or give me link for that?